# WSDL.EXE can not create proxy classes. error Schema item 'complexType' named ... The 'name' attribute cannot be present

Tags: xml, proxy, wsdl

I try execute in cmd:

`wsdl http://frgu.gosuslugi.ru/ws-services/registryInfoService`

And get error:

> Error: Schema item 'complexType' named 'filesListType' from namespace 'http://rg
>   u.lanit.ru/rev111111'.
>     - The 'name' attribute cannot be present.

I do not understand, why ?

xml is valid.